# Как исключить из списка максимальный элемент?

Tags: python

Как исключить из списка максимальный элемент?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
m_idx = 0
m_item = li[0]
for i, x in enumerate(li):
    if x > m_item:
        m_item = x
        m_idx = i

del li[m_idx]
```

Comment: Разве тут не 2 прохода? Первый на поиск, второй на удаление

Comment: @tayler Да, действительно, ошибся. Спасибо, что заметили. Но стоит сказать, что два прохода будут только в худшем случае, потому что удаление по индексу зависит от самого индекса — `O(N - i)` (сдвиг массива), т.е. у этого варианта асимптотика лучше, чем у стандартного метода. Но в ответах ниже добавили замеры скорости для `CPython` и оказалось, что  `li.remove(max(li))` всё-таки быстрее, потому что реализован на `C`.

Answer (score 12):

Так как спрашивали про самый быстрый, то рассмотрим все предложенные варианты плюс ещё один.

**1.** Первый предложенный вариант. Один из самых быстрых, несмотря на то что делается два прохода по списку и одно копирование хвоста после удаления:

```
def remove_max_1(a):
    a.pop(a.index(max(a)))
```

**2.** Самый худший вариант. Максимум отыскивается `N` раз. Квадратичная сложность, последнее место:

```
def remove_max_2(a):
    return [i for i in a if i != max(a)]
```

**3.** Оптимизация предыдущего варианта. Сложность стала линейной снова. Скорость не самая высокая, так как изготавливается копия:

```
def remove_max_3(a):
    v = max(a)
    return [i for i in a if i != v]
```

**4.** Вариация на тему первого. Вместо `pop` тут `del`:

```
def remove_max_4(a):
    del a[a.index(max(a))]
```

**5.** Самый элегантный вариант. Два прохода, одно копирование, как и у первого:

```
def remove_max_5(a):
    a.remove(max(a))
```

**6.** Максимальная оптимизация. Один проход, копирования нет. Вместо него последний элемент записывается на место максимального, затем список укорачивается на единицу. Не самый быстрый, как оказалось:

```
def remove_max_6(a):
    _, i = max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a))
    a[i] = a[-1]
    a.pop()
```

**7.** Отчаяная попытка сделать первый вариант ещё быстрее. Убрано копирование хвоста:

```
def remove_max_7(a):
    a[a.index(max(a))] = a[-1]
    a.pop()
```

**8.** Ещё один однопроходный способ. Этот лучше окровенно неудачного номера шестого, хотя есть копирование при удалении:

```
def remove_max_8(a):
    m_idx = 0
    m_item = a[0]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x > m_item:
            m_item = x
            m_idx = i
    del a[m_idx]
```

**9.** А можно найти максимум сортировкой за NlogN. Зато потом максимумы можно будет удалять без повторных сортировок, за константу:

```
def remove_max_9(a):
    a.sort()
    a.pop()
```

Таблица результатов:

```
n              10^3   10^4     10^5   10^6   10^7    10^8

remove_max_1  0.000  0.000    0.002  0.025  0.230   1.939
remove_max_2  0.016  1.483  147.792      -      -       -
remove_max_3  0.000  0.000    0.006  0.055  0.554   5.377
remove_max_4  0.000  0.000    0.002  0.026  0.231   1.964
remove_max_5  0.000  0.000    0.002  0.025  0.230   1.946
remove_max_6  0.000  0.001    0.013  0.121  1.215  12.128
remove_max_7  0.000  0.000    0.002  0.027  0.228   1.878
remove_max_8  0.000  0.000    0.005  0.045  0.480   4.659
remove_max_9  0.000  0.001    0.016  0.251  3.543  50.671
```

Хуже всех № 2 - О-большое не обманешь. № 9 - сортировка начинает бодро но отстаёт, опять О-большое. Оптимальный по количеству проходов № 6 не самый быстрый - один проход на Питоне хуже двух проходов на C. № 3 отстаёт так как создаёт копию списка. Лучшый из однопроходных № 8. Плотной группой идут №№ 1, 4, 5 - два прохода, одно копирование. В самом конце их немного обходит № 7 за счёт отказа от копирования.

Как проводились измерения

```
def elapsed_time(f):
    start = time.time()
    result = f()
    finish = time.time()
    return result, finish - start

def test(n, remove_max):
    r = random.Random(n)
    a = [r.random() for _ in range(n)]
    _, t = elapsed_time(lambda: remove_max(a))
    print(remove_max.__name__, '{:10d}'.format(n), '{:6.3f}'.format(t))

for p in range(1, 9):
    n = 10 ** p
    for rm in (remove_max_1, remove_max_2, remove_max_3, remove_max_4, remove_max_5, remove_max_6, remove_max_7, remove_max_8):
        test(n, rm)
```

Comment: А как Вы проводили измерения? Хочу повторить у себя

Comment: Добавил код в конец.

Comment: Спасибо большое за детальный разбор! Не ожидал, что `C` такой быстрый, и вариант с не самой лучшей асимптотикой в итоге окажется быстрее всех :) Стоит чаще уделять внимание практическим измерениям. Можно ещё на других интерпретаторах замерить, кстати. Потому что результат касается только `CPython`.

Comment: Добавьте и мой вариант, если не жалко )

Comment: Номер 9 добавлен по мотивам вашего. Нет, не жалко. :)

Comment: Кстати подумалось: а что если вместо чисел будет какой-нибудь произвольный класс? Придётся обращаться к питоновым `__eq__` и `__gt__` и возможно что-нибудь изменится?

Comment: Два прохода (поиск максимума и вычисление индекса) будут становится всё дороже и дороже. Полагаю что однопроходные алгоритмы вырвутся вперёд. Копирование хвоста потеряет своё значение полностью. Как-то так.

Answer (score 8):

Можно воспользоваться методом `remove`:

```py
li.remove(max(li))
```

Comment: О! У тебя лучше ;) Хотя мой возвращает этот элемент еще.

Comment: Два прохода по массивву, не круто

Comment: @andreymal Зато читаемо :) Я бы именно так и рекомендовал, если не стоит задачи оптимизировать код. Для примера добавил ещё один ответ за `O(N)`.

Comment: А я бы рекомендовал вынести оптимизированный код в функцию с читаемым названием :)

Comment: Не только красивый но и один из самых быстрых способов.

Answer (score 6):

```
your_list.pop(your_list.index(max(your_list)))
```

```
your_list = [i for in your_list if i != max(yourlist)]
```

Comment: А какой способ быстрее?

Comment: @tayler Вроде первый, с pop.

Comment: Тоже два прохода по массиву, тоже не круто. А во втором случае вообще len(your_list)+1 проходов, максимально не круто

Answer (score 5):

Все приведенные ответы неявно предполагают, что максимум в списке один.
Если это не так, они просто не решают поставленную задачу.
Вот решение.

```
li = [1,3,7,7,5,4,2,1,7]
li.sort()
index = li.index(li[-1])
del li[index:]
```

наслаждайтесь.
Да, мы проигрываем на первом этапе сортировки. Это n*ln(n) операций. Однако, если максимумов 2 или более в списке, то поиск очередного из них в несортированном списке оценивается как n/2.
То есть нам надо выбирать между n*ln(n)  как в приведенном здесь алгоритме и предыдущими алгоритмами n + n/2*k, где k  -  это количество максимумов в исходном списке )

Comment: Удалить се максимальные элементы разом можно за линейное время без сортировки. Варианты, которы изготавливают копии списка по условию `v != max(a)` так и работают. Но можно и без копирования добится того же.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  отлично. можно ссылку на алгоритм, который удаляет все максимальные элементы?
И у меня написано же - что надо выбирать один из алгоритмов в зависимости от n )
.
Понятно, что при больших массивах это не выгодно

Comment: [remove_all.py](https://gist.github.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/5cfc60ff8e431ff9c6524cf87d307e7a)

Answer (score 3):

1. найти максимальный элемент и индекс в массиве

2.1) собрать новый список из старого без максимального элемента

2.2) удалить максимальный элемент по индексу через

```
del arr[index_max]
```

Answer (score 3):

Случайно код получился как из другого ответа от nomnoms12, но хочу отправить ;)

```
def del_max_fast(arr):
    biggest = arr[0]
    index_of_biggest = 0
    for index, element in enumerate(arr):
        if element > biggest:
            biggest, index_of_biggest = element, index
    del arr[index_of_biggest]
    return arr
```